# Только CSS. Смещение по уровню выше и ниже или следующий по коду тег

Tags: css

```
<div>
 title 1
 <div class="a1"> text 1 </div>
 <div> text 2 </div>
</div>
```

1. Есть ли возможность через CSS зацепиться за "div.a1" и от него пойти выше на 1 ступень, что-бы изменить цвет текста "title 1" ?
2. Есть ли возможность через CSS зацепиться за "div.a1" и от него пойти к следующему тегу на текущем уровне и изменить цвет "text 2" ?

Просто если использовать `div.a1 { color:red; }` то цвет измениться только в "text 1".
По этому меня интересует что нужно дописать слева или справа от **div.a1** что-бы выбрать выше на 1 уровень и изменить цвет "title 1" или соседний "text 2". И есть ли вообще такая возможность через CSS?

Comment: Второй пункт делается так: `div.a1 + div { color: green }`

Answer (score 1):

В CSS есть 2 относительных селектора:

1. `el1 ~ el2` – выбрать все `el2`, которые идут после `el1` на том же уровне вложенности.
2. `el1 + el2` – выбрать `el2`, который идёт сразу после `el1` на том же уровне вложенности.

Если со вторым всё понятно, то первый селектор `el1 ~ el2` открывает довольно большие возможности. Можно объявить якоря `el1` где-нибудь *по-выше* в DOM, тогда мы можем использовать элемент якоря как переменную, управляя классами, атрибутами и прочими свойствами которого мы можем управлять отображением хоть всей страницей.

Приведу пример. Простые табы на CSS.

В качестве якоря возьмем несколько `<input type="radio"/>`.

Переключение radio-боксов будут транслировать ярлыки табов `<label for="...">`.

Содержание всех табов будет скрыто. Но активный таб будет отображаться благодаря селекторам типа `input:checked ~ .tab-panels div`. Обратите внимание, что сам `<div>` с активной панелью содержания находится после выделенного `<input>`, но не на том же уровне, - он вложен в другой блок с классом `tab-panels`. В таком случае участие  `.tab-panels` в селекторе `input:checked ~ .tab-panels div` обязательно, без него селектор работать не будет, так как просто не найдёт нужный `div`.

Приложив к подобным подходам голову, можно использовать эти селекторы для неограниченной динамики страницы на чистом CSS.

Помимо `<input type="radio">` совместно с `label` часто используют `<input type="checkbox">`. Хотя, по сути, в качестве якоря можно использовать элементы любого типа.

```js
                /* Этот пример сделан без использования JavaScript */
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
}

/* Для начала скроем от глаз якорный <input> */

input[name="tab-input"] {
  display: none;
}

/* Стили ярлыков табов <label> */

.tab-labels label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s;
  transition-property: background, top;
}

.tab-labels label:hover{
  background: #ffd;
  top: 2px;
}

/* Обратите внимание на селекторы */
#tab1-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab1-label,
#tab2-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab2-label,
#tab3-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab3-label {
  transition: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

#tab1-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab1-label::after,
#tab2-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab2-label::after,
#tab3-input:checked~.tab-labels #tab3-label::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  left: -10px;
  top: 25%;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
  transition: 0;
}

/* Стили панелей содержания табов */

.tab-panels div {
  /* по умолчанию - все они скрыты */
  display: none; 
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  height: calc( 100vh - 80px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#tab1-input:checked~.tab-panels #tab1-panel,
#tab2-input:checked~.tab-panels #tab2-panel,
#tab3-input:checked~.tab-panels #tab3-panel {
  /* но активная таба отображается */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tab-input" value="tab1" id="tab1-input" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="tab-input" value="tab2" id="tab2-input" />
<input type="radio" name="tab-input" value="tab3" id="tab3-input" />

<div class="tab-labels">
  <label id="tab1-label" for="tab1-input">Таб 1</label>
  <label id="tab2-label" for="tab2-input">Таб 2</label>
  <label id="tab3-label" for="tab3-input">Таб 3</label>
</div>

<div class="tab-panels">
  <div id="tab1-panel">Содержание таба 1</div>
  <div id="tab2-panel">Содержание таба 2</div>
  <div id="tab3-panel">Содержание таба 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. к сожалению пока нет в том виде разметки, что вы привели - свойства объекта всегда читаются слева направо

можно конечно сделать финт ушами, эффект будет схожий, но это не истинное обращение к элементу выше -

надо определить свойства для всех элементом главного `div` (в вашем примере), а потом использовать 2) для определения `.a1` и того, что ниже `.a1`

но это частные случаи, например при разметке где выше `.a1` несколько `div`, а не один трюк уже не сработает

2. да, можно, на этом принципе основаны всякие выпадающие списки, переопределение стандартных кнопок и т.д.

используйте `.a1 + div`

```css
.a1 + div {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 title 1
 <div class="a1"> text 1 </div>
 <div> text 2 </div>
 <div> text 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задаём всем div один цвет, потом задаём цвет a1, а потом задаём следующему элементу после a1 и все три элемента окрасятся в свой цвет.

```css
div {
  color: yellow;
}
div.a1 {
  color: red;
}
div.a1 + div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
 title 1
 <div class="a1"> text 1 </div>
 <div> text 2 </div>
</div>
```